# Swagger ui not working properly when using grape with versions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, swagger, swagger-ui

If I load the content of 'http://local.myproject:3000/api/swagger'

The api endpoints are shown as '/api/0.1/activities.json' despite the fact that my version is 'V1'

```
version 'v1', using: :path do
  mount TheLocker::Ping
  ...
```

Exactly by this reason when I push the 'Try it out!' button on the 'swagger ui' the request can't be executed because the version part of the api is not matching the actual one.

This is part of the message the swagger UI is displaying:

```
"No route matches [GET] &quot;/api/0.1/activities.json&quot;"
```

Comment: is that a problem with swagger-ui, or rather your swagger files (i.e. api-docs.json)? I figure the wrong paths are specified there. How do you generate your swagger files?

Comment: the swagger is generated automatically by the grape gem...

Comment: okay, I am not familiar with grape/grape-swagger, but I am pretty sure that the error is somewhere in your grape-swagger setup and not in swagger-ui. I suggest changing your question in that respect, so people familiar with grape have a chance to stumble over it and help you

Comment: I changed the title of the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @Peter Sorowka, you gave me a good hint to find the root of the problem.

Here: https://github.com/tim-vandecasteele/grape-swagger#configure it states that we can specify the version for the swagger to document.

So I needed to add the api_version: 'v1' to the mounting point:

```
add_swagger_documentation api_version: 'v1'
```